# DDSmoothmenu (Dynamic Drive) displaying expanded menu while loading page (ugly!)

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

My site is located at http://www.idataresearch.net

I'm using Dynamic Drive's ddmoothmenu script for the navigation menu.  I really love this script and was happy to see that the previous developer implemented it in our site.  However, for whatever reason it displays the fully expanded menus for the split second it takes to load the page.

I've tried display: none on the smoothmenu1 div and the creating this function:

```
function showDiv();
  $(#smoothmenu1).show();
}
```

and then

but that didn't work.  Can someone have a look at my code and let me know what I'm missing to solve this problem ... thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error to your code.

Try this

```
function showDiv() {
  $('#smoothmenu1').show();
}
```

Comment: Yah, sorry, it was a typo.  It doesn't actually show the div.

Comment: aha, I figured it out. Wordpress doesn't allow "$" for jQuery. After switching "$" to "jQuery", it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see a few errors.  Assuming you didn't typo it, your Javascript should read:

```
function showDiv() {
  $('#smoothmenu1').show();
}
```

Edit: I meant to mention: your question says that your problem has to do with the menu showing for a split-second.  This is known as a flash of unstyled content (FOUC). Javascript to remedy this should be triggered on document load, which would read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#smoothmenu1').show();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I know it should work.  But there is something else preventing it from working.

Comment: aha, I figured it out.  Wordpress doesn't allow "$" for jQuery.  After switching "$" to "jQuery", it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution ... not as short as suggested above but in my opinion working better, because the menu doesn't disapear for a while. I took the css file ddsmoothmenu-v.css in my case, copy and paste whole content, so I have twice the same styles, then I replace in one copy class .ddsmoothmenu with id of the outer div #lmenu in my case ... so the menu is immadiately styled before the inicialization of the menu.